# Integrate Quickbooks as a payment method on website

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce, payment, quickbooks-online

I need to integrate QuickBook as a payment method with a website. For this, I would like to connect to QuickBook and create an invoice or payments links and redirect customers to them as I do it with Paypal and after catch the webhooks from QuickBooks about payment status.

Here is a page for paying with Quickbook (You can make a payment link manually in your account):
[image]

I want to create such links with api for php (laravel). There is no api for directly creating payment link though api, but there is an option to create invoices with link. I've managed to create such invoices calling the QuickBooks api through Postman but that link doesn't work. It opens an error page.

[image]

Here is that page:
[image]

There is no much information about paying on the website with QuickBooks, so I am not quite sure is this task a achievable. But if anyone did something similar or has some experience with integration QuickBook to e-commercial websites, please give me a hint

Answer (score 1):

The thing was that the QB has an error in sandbox mode. If you try to call this route in live mode everything will work. Here is a link for my issue on the Intuit Developer Forum https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/feed/0D54R00008D4MIwSAN

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to do is set up your application on Quickbooks Online. Here is a Quickstart guide: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/get-started

Then you should consider using the PHP client library for OAuth: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/oauth-2.0

Then you can start looking through the Quickbooks Online API, and see if they have API to solve your needs: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/most-commonly-used/account